# Echarts 3 - Bipartite chart

Tags: charts, data-visualization, bipartite, echarts

1) Is it possible to create a bipartite chart using ECharts 3?

Something like: http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/3ba0031d3d555afca4713e5264455025

2) Can be used a 'chord' chart in ECharts 3?

Example with ECharts 2: http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/chord1.html#-en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it's possible. With echarts you can do almost any type of chart. Take a look at "Sankey" examples:
   https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/#chart-type-sankey
2. I'd recommend to use demo for echarts 3, your example is for echarts 2
   https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=graph-circular-layout

Most of echarts 3 demos work with the latest echarts 4, the only thing not working in echarts 4 are stacked line charts but I made an issue for that https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts/issues/7549